# sql server 2008 r2 database downgrade

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to downgrade a database, that has been created on SQL Server 2008 R2, to work on an older version of SQL Server 2008 (RTM/SP1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There is no way to downgrade a database once it was upgraded. You can only extract all the tables and all the data and import them into an RTM/SP1 database.